# Can matrices work with vectors instead of scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrices work well when their elements are numbers.

For instance, this system of linear equaltions:

$$
\begin{cases}
  a_{00} x_0 + a_{01} x_1 = b_0 \\
  a_{10} x_0 + a_{11} x_1 = b_1
\end{cases}
$$

where $a_{ij} \in R, x_i \in R, y_i \in R$ can be expressed as matrix equation:

$$
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{00} & a_{01} \\
    a_{10} & a_{11}
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{A}
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    x_0 \\ x_1
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{x} =
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    b_0 \\ b_1
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{b}
$$

or like vector equation:

$$
\underbrace{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{0} \\
    a_{1}
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{A} x =b
$$

or even shorter: $Ax = b$. This way we can find solution as $x = A^{-1}b$.

Of course, there is **a lot** of stuff under the hood: determinant, adjugate matrix, minors, etc.
But as a result we can find $x$ if all $a$, $b$ and $x$ are numbers.

Can we do the same with vectors? When $a_{ij}, b_i, x_i \in R^{2}$.

Can we do the same using the same or similar set of rules?

Is there a branch of mathematics that studies matrices built on top of vectors instead of scalars?

Like... systems of linear equations **of systems** of linear equations?

Does that make eny sense?

Comment: You need to specify what it means then for the multiplication of two vectors - matrices work because you can multiply scalars together, so then you can multiply two matrices or one matrix and a vector through the usual formulas. If you define vector multiplication, then sure, you indeed can talk about matrices with entries among those vectors.

Comment: In fact, in that case you’re not just dealing with plain vectors, but vectors with some kind of multiplication structure. Depending on what exactly you want, you would be either talking about rings, over algebras (over some field). And indeed then you have the matrix ring (or algebra) with entries in the said ring (or algebra). This is a useful concept in various fields of algebra (and sometimes analysis).

Comment: I think you’ll find that you need $a_{ij}$ to be $2\times 2$ matrices for what you’re thinking/writing to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, putting vectors (either elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, or vectors in the more general sense of elements of a vector space, like functions) as entries of a matrix makes sense, at least when restricting the use of that matrix to matrix-vector products (representing a linear combination of the columns of the matrix, as usual). It's a bit of an abuse of notation but the intended meaning is fairly clear. I've also seen the opposite: an ordinary matrix of scalar multiplying a vector whose entries aren't scalar (for example: the matrix form of the Frenet–Serret equation).

However, I do not recommend your notation (which implies some kind of vector-vector product between the $a_i$ and $x$, and is likely to confuse readers). To write your equation as a matrix of vectors I would instead do

$$\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{a}_{\star 0} & \mathbf{a}_{\star 1}\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$$
where the $\mathbf{a}_{\star i}$ are column vectors.

Note that tensors are essentially the "matrices built on top of vectors" that you're looking for (and you can represent the matrix-vector multiplication in terms of contraction of the tensor).